# How can I distinguish between requests made from RenderAction and via AJAX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, xmlhttprequest, request

In ASP.NET MVC, there is a useful method `Request.IsAjaxRequest` that I can use to determine whether the request is made via AJAX. However, `RenderAction` method seems to be calling the controller/action via AJAX as well.

I would like the calls via `RenderAction` to return a `View`, whereas calls via AJAX to return a `Json` object. Is there any way I can distinguish calls from those two sources?

**EDIT**: 
Re. jim: I simply call a `RenderAction` within a `View`:

In `SomeView.ascx`:

```
Html.RenderAction("Action", "AnotherController", new { id = "some ID" });
```

Comment: william, i beg to differ on your statement re RenderAction. the same test applies [Request.IsAjaxRequest()] on renderaction. it certainly deosn't get invoked via ajax by default. you should check over your code to ensure that you don't have some jquery invoking renderaction 'under the covers'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you could use `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` to determine if a method was called by `RenderAction()`.